# How to join 2 images in google app engine

Tags: image, google-app-engine

How can I join 2 images/append in google app engine?
I cannot find any transform that does it.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like indeed there is no transformation that does it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `composite()` function. You don't say which language you're using, so here's the docs [in Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions.html) and [in Java](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService.html#composite%28java.util.Collection,%20int,%20int,%20long,%20com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesService.OutputEncoding%29).